# String to double conversion allways 0

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to read a double precision floating point number from a binary file and assign it to a static double variable. I have tried numerous methods however the result of the conversion regardless of the method is 0.The number is correctly read from the file(as an array of characters), however something happens when I try to convert it... The included headers are: # include < string > # include < sstream > #include < stdlib.h >

The code snippet of the method is given bellow:

```
FILE * pFile;
char mystring [100];
double v;
string temp;
QString t_string;
pFile = fopen ("path_to_binary_file","r");
if (pFile != NULL)
{
   if ( fgets (mystring , 100 , pFile) != NULL )
    {
     //I am putting a \0 on the last position since my array finishes with  \n
    mystring[strlen(mystring) - 1] = '\0';

   temp.assign(mystring, mystring + 12);
   t_string = QString::fromStdString(temp);
  //  std::istringstream s(temp);
   // s >> sheethConstant;

    v = t_string.toDouble();//atof(mystring);
    static_variable = v;
   }
fclose (pFile);
}
```

Comment: What's the value of the QString?

Comment: `std::stod("1234.56")`.

Comment: You must also be including some Qt header as well as the ones mentioned.

Comment: I have also included QString, and I have also tried std::stod and strtod. The value from the file is 0,04019173434

Comment: `0,04019173434` won't be converted unless you have set the appropriate `locale` I believe, and I don't know how to do that with `QString`.

Comment: well, I have tried to convert it using string or atof but the result is the same. The QString conversion method is just of the multiple methods I have tried...If you know any other way in which I could convert the string to double I would appreciate the help!

Comment: It should be possible to set a locale object with `QLocale` that takes into account the decimal separator and then create a QString from double with `QLocale::toString` and convert a string to a double with `QLocale::toDouble`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the decimal separator is a comma you must handle with locale.

Since you're using Qt is possible to set a `QLocale` object and setting a locale that uses the comma (I've only take one that works, it's not specific to your situation).

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QLocale>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QString t_string("0,04019173434");
  QLocale locale(QLocale::Catalan);
  double number = locale.toDouble(t_string);
  qDebug() << "String is" << t_string << ", number is " << number;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good to know that. For future reference please specify the comma stuff in your question and not only in the comment.